# Instagram max_tag_id from media id?

Tags: instagram

Is there a way to "calculate" the max_tag_id from a media id in Instagram Api paging without getting it from a /media/recent query ?

Or can anyone exlplain more exactly what the max_tag_id is or where it comes from ?

/b

Comment: Agree - its not clear